# qt c++ gui 'on_lineEdit'

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm new to qt and to c++ and have run into something that I can't solve by searching the internet. First, here is the code in question:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_3_textChanged(const QString &arg1) //check for hex or octal     
{
QString text = ui -> lineEdit_3 -> text();
QString y = text.mid(0, 1);
int n = text.size();
{
    if (y == "0")
      {
        if (n > 1)
        {
            text = "Dec. only";
            ui -> lineEdit_3 -> setText("");
        }
      }
 }
ui -> lineEdit -> setText(text);

}
```

This works fine, but when I come back to the editor after running, I have a message at the bottom of the screen:

> Unused parameter 'arg1' [-Wunused parameter]

I am sure it is referring to the `&arg1` in the first line, however I have no idea what `arg1` would be used for or how to use it. Can anyone direct me to information about its use, or tutorial on its use?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: "This property holds the line edit's text." arg1 must be the current text. For more info, read [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#text-prop).

Comment: Yes, I saw that before asking my question. It just doesn't make any sense to me....

Answer (score 0):

This line is not necessary, since you already have the text in `arg1`.

```
QString text = ui -> lineEdit_3 -> text();
```

Then you can use the following to get the first character from the textfield.

```
QChar y = arg1.at(0);
```

Comment: Thank you! however, I need to get the entire line of text, not just the first character. The first character is used to help determine if it is hex or octal. A little more information: I'm using this to read data without having to click on anything. When the user changes the lineedit_3 box, I want to be able to automatically read and use it to set a variable. Is there a better way to do this than with 'on_lineEdit_3_textChanged'?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that exact message because in your function definition you have `const QString &arg1`, however you've not used it within your function itself as instead you're retrieving the text with `ui->lineEdit_3->text()`. The `arg1` parameter is the text contained in the `ui->lineEdit_3` after it has been changed, so you don't need to retrieve it with the call to `->text()`.

Side tip, you can squash the warning message with `Q_UNUSED(someParameterName)`, but it flags a warning message for a reason.

Comment: Ah, just a glimmer of understanding now. But, how do I extract the arg1?

Comment: So `arg1` is passed by the signal into your function, within your function you can just use `arg1` as it's already defined. So where you have:
 `QString text = ui -> lineEdit_3 -> text();
  QString y = text.mid(0, 1);`

You can use this instead:
 `QString y = arg1.mid(0,1);`